# DOM loads slowly, causing Inbox icon click to go to stackexchange.com

Tags: bug

Since a couple of days the frontpage of https://stackoverflow.com/ loads relatively slowly, as in 0.7-1.2 seconds of load time of which 500-1000 ms is spent rendering the DOM.

This causes the click handler attached to the Inbox icon to attach relatively late, so when you click it while the page is still loading, you navigate to its href instead, being `https://stackexchange.com/users/$userid/$username?tab=inbox`.

I encounter this in Chrome 68.

So:

1. Click the Stack Overflow logo to go to the homepage
2. Notice you have messages in your Inbox, indicated by a red icon
3. While the page is loading, click the icon
4. Instead of the Inbox dropdown opening, you're redirected to your inbox on Stack Exchange

This happens quite often lately, and it's annoying. Did you change anything, or should I buy a CPU with a couple more cores?

Demonstration:

[image: Fatality]

Comment: Can't reproduce this in the latest Chrome (/win 10). Even with my gamer-reflexes, I can't click the "inbox" icon before the DOM is done.

Comment: @Cerbrus probably we are hitting some bad build.

Comment: This also happens for me when I open my browser with my 20+ tabs all opened.

Comment: @Cerbrus well I'm a (poor) FPS gamer as well, but I wanted to make note of this so if other people experience it as well, we can console each other that we aren't going crazy.

Comment: No repro on Chrome/IE/Edge. With a WPrime to benchmark the proc, and slow the loading.

Comment: I had a similar issue some years ago, it was caused by me disabling all caching in the browser's developer tools and forgetting about it.

Comment: Your FPS-fu shows. 3 frames to move the cursor from the link to the inbox button!

Comment: @Cerbrus yet I haven't ever hit anyone in PUBG...

Comment: I managed to reproduce this by aligning the "back" context menu option with the button, then spamming my mouse button... Nothing that can really be fixed, I think.

Comment: I couldn't recreate this from the computer browser but I could from mobile chome; clicking right away takes me to stack exchange but waiting about 5 seconds then clicking opens the inbox.

Comment: Feel free to reopen if not exact dupe.. or ping me